# Database.database() Error cannor find in scope>

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete a table view cell in swift and when I delete the cell I also need to delete the data in firebase. So I use `Database.database().child("tweet")` this is where the error is it says cannot find Database in scope.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Firestore
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var db:Firestore!
    var tweetArray = [tweet]()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()
        checkForUpdates()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        Database.database().child("tweet")    "Error cannot find Database in scope"
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("tweet").getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                self.tweetArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({tweet(dictionary: $0.data())})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
    func checkForUpdates() {
        db.collection("tweet").whereField("timeStamp", isGreaterThan: Date())
            .addSnapshotListener {
                querySnapshot, error in
                guard let snapshots = querySnapshot else {return}
                
                snapshots.documentChanges.forEach {
                    diff in
                    
                    if diff.type == .added {
                    self.tweetArray.append(tweet(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func composeSweet(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let composeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Employee", message: "Add Employee", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }
        
        composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Adress"
        }
    
        
        composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Employee", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            
            if let name = composeAlert.textFields?.first?.text,
               let content = composeAlert.textFields?.last?.text {
                let newTweet = tweet(name: name, content: content,timeStamp: Date())
                
                var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
            
                ref = self.db.collection("tweet").addDocument(data: newTweet.dictionary) {
                    error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }else{
                        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        
        self.present(composeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return tweetArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let tweet1 = tweetArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(tweet1.name) \(tweet1.content)"
        cell .detailTextLabel?.text = "\(tweet1.timeStamp) "
        

        return cell
    }
}
```

I tried importing different firebase imports and that didn't work i'm not sure if it has something to do with my cocoa pods. these are the cocapods I have downloaded: pod 'Firebase/Core
pod 'Firebase/Auth' pod 'Firestore'

Comment: have you tried installing `FirebaseDatabase` and then using `import FirebaseDatabase`

Comment: You need to add `Firebase/Firestore` to your podfile and then import it into your Swift file with `import FirebaseFirestore`. Then you access Firestore with `Firestore.firestore()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reading data with:

```
db.collection("tweet").whereField("timeStamp", isGreaterThan: Date())
```

This is the API for Cloud Firestore, a NoSQL document database that is part of  Firebase.

---

You then try to also access data with:

```
Database.database().child("tweet")
```

This is using the API for the Realtime Database, which is also a part of Firebase but it is a completely separate product with its own API.

---

To prevent more problems, use only the API for the database you're actually using, which seems to be Firestore. Have a look at the documentation on [deleting data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)